# loadUrl from String[] and set in onClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I want load url in onClick listView by select position But this code have error in this line `webview.loadUrl(getString(Slecteditem));`

```
   ListView  list;

    String[]  url      = {
                        "https://www.google.com",
                       "https://www.ask.com",
                       "https://www.yahoo.com",
                       "https://www.facebook.com"};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View V = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), itemname, imgid);
        list = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String Slecteditem = url[ +position];

                WebView webview = (WebView) V.findViewById(R.id.webView);
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webview.loadUrl(getString(Slecteditem));
            }
        });
        return V;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set in webview:

```
webview.loadUrl(Slecteditem);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String url=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
webview.loadUrl(url);
```